# Inconsistency in web view on orientation change

Tags: android, webview

There are three web views in my activity . On changing the  orientation of the device screen starts shaking/Flickering continuously.  Below is the log which is printed multiple times. Can any one help me to resolve this.

02-11 17:14:04.258: V/webcore(29006): webkitDraw NEW_PICTURE_MSG_ID
02-11 17:14:04.258: V/webview(29006): UPDATE_TEXT_ENTRY_MSG_ID
02-11 17:14:04.258: V/webcore(29006): UPDATE_CACHE_AND_TEXT_ENTRY arg1=0 arg2=0 obj=null
02-11 17:14:04.298: V/webcore(29006): VIEW_SIZE_CHANGED arg1=0 arg2=0 obj=android.webkit.WebView$ViewSizeData@56f44478
02-11 17:14:04.298: V/webcore(29006): viewSizeChanged w=460; h=103; textwrapWidth=460; scale=1.0
02-11 17:14:04.298: V/webcore(29006): WEBKIT_DRAW arg1=0 arg2=0 obj=null

Answer (score 0):

try using
`android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` in the manifest file for the webview